# How to programmatically set a xml setting as selected

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences, settings

I have the following code in my xml resource for my settings menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="top_rated"
        android:dialogTitle="Search for:"
        android:entries="@array/SettingEntries"
        android:entryValues="@array/SettingEntriesValue"
        android:key="pref_sync"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:title="Show" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

When my app loads the first time, i dont want it to load the stored value from the previous run, but select the first value on the list.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedPrefs.edit().putString("pref_sync", "top_rated");
```

I tried to change the value in SharedPreferences when the app gets created but that didn't work. Any advice on how to solve the matter?

Comment: What do you mean by you don't want to load the stored value? Do you not want to persist the selected option for next lunch of the app, just storing for the current session?

Comment: Say my list is made up of 3 items. On the last run i had item 3 selected so when i open the app again, i want it to go back to the first item n the list.

Comment: Have you tried to clear the shared preferences or remove this entry on app start?

Comment: what im doing in that snippet of code is exactly that.